# What is a good tool to make good looking mathematical animations?

Tags: education

I want to make educational videos related to math and physics, I can handle the visuals of physics with Adobe AE, but the math part of it needs to be there too, so if anybody has some has some suggestions, please leave them.

What I want:

- Good looking animations (Youtube)

  The ability to graph functions, fully and partially (for ex, the arc of a circle, which increases over time), with the options of having a visible grid/axes (This one must be switchable for both, since there are times when there's no need for both, and times when both are needed)

  The output should be in a common format (.mkv, .mp4, img sequence or something)

Comment: I did something like that in Mathematica. You have to pay for it though.

Comment: @Kaster I'm not really familiar with Mathematica, but isn't it a CAS?

Comment: Mathematica can animate. Also, [3blue1brown](http://www.3blue1brown.com) animates his videos in python and releases the source for all his animations. Might be worth a look. I made [this gif](http://folk.uio.no/maartena/Movie.gif) in MATLAB a while back, I'm sure it can be done in Octave as well. Basically, there are lots of options.

Comment: @Arthur I actually took a look at his tools, they're fairly complex, and a bit too inflexible for what i need. As for MATLAB, can you tell me if it's possible to change background colors and other visuals? Since I AM animating for a video.

Comment: @Arthur Also, are the same features available in Octave? That seems more to my liking (since I don't really have a budget, spent everything on Adobe's license)

Comment: One option is using WebGL and a javascript library that helps out. For example, the MathBox Library is pretty cool and high level. https://acko.net/blog/making-mathbox/ If you want more control over what you are animating, try ThreeJS. The benefit of using these tools is that they are free, require minimal setup, and all you need is a browser to run them

Comment: You can see many mathematical animations I've made in Matlab in the links provided in my profile.

Comment: Octave is meant to be a free MATLAB clone. Or, almost meant to be one (I think they say they want to be better than MATLAB, which necessarily means different in some respect). Most things MATLAB can do, Octave can do. As for the python tools, I haven't actually looked at them myself, so you might be right.

Comment: As for what's possible, simple graphics changes like background color and axes should be possible and quite easy (although background color in particular depends on what backend you use; gnuplot can't change background color, while openGL can from what I can tell from a quick google search). More complicated graphic stuff, like changing the texture of a surface, is probably a lot harder and the possibilities more limited.

Comment: @JonathanDavidson The options you provided seems enticing, but do they have a method to convert the output into a common format?

Comment: You need to elaborate to what context. There are some code libraries that convert webgl javascript into a gif file.

Comment: @JonathanDavidson The original question should answer that

Comment: you are right. Well couldn't he just use OBS to record his screen while webgl applications are running, and convert it to whatever format he wants?

Comment: @JonathanDavidson No other, more elegant solution?

Comment: None that i can think of. I looked up ways in which the webgl programs could be converted to other video formats, and it seems you are going to have to rely on some github project for the conversions.

Comment: @JonathanDavidson Yeah, I'll probably just use openframeworks..